# Chrome weird outline on faux-bolded fonts depending on size

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face, font-size, webfonts

[image: Chrome Windows]

Chrome on Windows ^^^^

[image]

Chrome on Firefox^^^^

This seems to only happen at certain sizes and letters when the font in question does not have a supplied "bold" weight but one is declared in the styles. This "faux" bold is fine for all characters in Firefox, but not in Chrome (as of 109.0.5414.75) on Windows. As you change the size, even by fractions of pixels, it can come and go with no rhyme or reason.

Here is a codepen that illustrates the issue if you are in Windows Chrome: https://codepen.io/harrison-rood/pen/wvxyQer

```
<style>
body {
      line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #212529;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:400;
}

.ct-text-block {
  font-family:"Average";
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: .75em;
    margin-bottom: .5px;
     font-size: 1em;
  /*change the above to font-size:1.01em to fix the issue*/
}
.larger{
  font-size:16.5px
}</style><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Average&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<body> <p>This seems to only happen at certain sizes, in this case 16px, and letters (K & R) when the font in question does not have a supplied "bold" weight but one is declared in the styles. This "faux" bold is fine for all characters in Firefox, but not in Chrome (as of 109.0.5414.75) on Windows. </p><div id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">Here are Faux Bold  characters at 16px:AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGGG HHHH III JJJ KK LLL MMM NN OOO PPP QQQ RRR SSS TTT UUU VVV WWW XXX YYY ZZZ</span>

  <div id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block larger"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">Here are Faux Bold  characters at 16.5px:AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGGG HHHH III JJJ KK LLL MMM NN OOO PPP QQQ RRR SSS TTT UUU VVV WWW XXX YYY ZZZ</span>
</div>
   <div style="font-size:2em" id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">2em (32px): KK RRR</span>
</div>
    <div style="font-size:34px"  id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">34px: KK RRR</span>
</div>
     <div style="font-size:5em" id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">5em (80px): KK RRR</span>
</div>
    <div style="font-size:90px"  id="text_block-13-57265" class="ct-text-block"><span id="span-14-57265" class="ct-span">90px: KK RRR</span>
</body>
```

The font is not installed locally, as I've seen that be the cause in other cases. This is also not limited to my computer, as I've test a few others both on Win 11 and 10 and the same thing happens. Mac seems to work fine regardless of browser, at least in my limited testing.

I would expect that fonts would render consistently between characters, even if those results were sub-optimal. I know the faux-bold probably throws a wrench in everything, but its weird that some characters work consistently, and others break depending on size.

The font is not installed locally, as I've seen that be the cause in other cases. This is also not limited to my computer, as I've test a few others both on Win 11 and 10 and the same thing happens. Mac seems to work fine regardless of browser, at least in my limited testing.